# Change string upper from space

Tags: c#

How can I change first string from lower to upper after whitespace in textbox when textbox changed?

I am using WPF and C# code.

For example When I type in textbox "new textbox string", string in textbox must be change automaticaly to "New Textbox String"

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us examples of input/output?  Above you mention first string, there is only one string, do you mean first word in a string?  A lot or information is needed to help out.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and you have not included the code you have so far.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information: Try to describe, where your "textbox" is (Winforms?WPF?ASP.NET), and give an example of the source string and your desired output ("New Textbox String" => "New TEXTBOX String"?).

Comment: More information was provided, I'm voting to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need an event handler for the textbox changed event (not sure if this is WinForms, WPF, or whatever).

In that event handler, you can loop through each character position in the string, adding each character to a new StringBuilder.  If the character at a given index is white space (use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)), set a flag that you need to capitalize the next alpha character.

If you hit an alpha character, and the previous flag is set, instead copy the upper case equivalent of the character (use [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and clear the flag.

Set the contents of the textbox to myStringBuilder.ToString().

Depending on the UI framework in question, it may generate a new text changed event that you need to ignore to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event.  Then you can use the `TextInfo` [`ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) function to convert the first character of each word to a capital letter.

```
System.Globalization.TextInfo en_text_info = 
   new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
textBox1.Text = en_text_info.ToTitleCase(textBox1.Text);
```

This would convert something like `"hi thEre how R yOu dOINg?"` to `"Hi There How R You Doing?"`

Comment: I add **textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length+1, 1);**